Extend of numerical ODE for a special case
I want to continue the plot but I don't know how to do it?
         Clear["Global`*"];
         g[x_] := Sqrt[(1 - 0.31 + 0.31)/x^2 + 0.31/x^3 - 0.31];

         (*Solve the differential equation numerically*)

         sol = NDSolve[{x'[t]/x[t] == g[x[t]], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, -2, 2}];

         Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, -5, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 3}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "a"}, PlotTheme -> {"Detailed"},PlotLegends -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x[t]"}]


Since you solved the ode for {t, -2, 2} and trying to plot for {t, -5, 5} then extrapolation is used automatically. But this can lead to bad results. Also notice the warning from NDSolve about singularity or stiff system encountered. You need to first solve that before worrying about the plot part. This seems similar question to one asked here recently.

I reduced the problem to an easy one but please let me know how to solve it properly?!! i need this extrapolation

DSolve[x'[t]/x[t] ==
Sqrt[(1 - 0.31 + 0.31)/x[t]^2 + 0.31/x[t]^3 - 0.31], x[t], t]

Mathematica can actually solve this  analytically, using DSolve. But the solution is implicit, and in terms of ellipticF function which Mathematica can't isolate. ps. when using DSolve change all decimal numbers to exact numbers. It is better this way. so change 0.31 to 31/100 and so on...  This does not look like an easy ode to solve.

But how to plot this?

Can't plot the analytical solution since the solution is implicit. Mathematica can't solve for $x(t)$ that is why it gives it using Solve[....] form.  Have to run now. Hopefully someone will have better ideas.

So I guess NDSolve it is better for my result

Clear["Global`*"];
g[x_] := Sqrt[1/x^2 + 0.31/x^3 - 0.31];

(*Solve the differential equation numerically*)

 sol = NDSolve[{x'[t]/x[t] == g[x[t]], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, -2, 2}];

 P1 = Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, -5, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 3}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "x[t]"}, PlotTheme -> {"Detailed"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]

 g1[x_] := Sqrt[1/x^2 + a/x^3 - a];
 A = DSolve[{x'[t]/x[t] == g1[x[t]], x[0] == 1}, x[t], t];
 Z = Table[{s, 
 x /. FindRoot[(((A[[1]][[1]] - A[[1]][[2]]) /. x[t] -> x) /. 
      a -> 31/100) /. t -> s, {x, 1/2}]}, {s, -1, 5, 1/12}] // Quiet;
 Show[{ListLinePlot[Z // Re, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 3}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Green}], P1}]


For time:  $t>1.76$ I don't know  if FindRoot gave a correct solution.
UPDATED:
 Clear["Global`*"];
 g[x_] := Sqrt[1/x^2 + 0.31/x^3 - 0.31];
 sol = NDSolve[{x'[t]/x[t] == g[x[t]], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, -5, 5}, 
 Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}] // Quiet;
 Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, -5, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 3}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "x[t]"}, PlotTheme -> {"Detailed"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic] // Quiet



Thank you, this is the method I was looking for

@FelipeDura Why haven't you accepted any answers to your questions and why haven't you upvoted right answers?
